# Combine multiple iOS apps into a single bookshelf-type app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have developed individual children storybook apps as standalone iOS apps, but now planning to release it on the app store as a single bookshelf-type of app. Using the bookshelf-type app, users should be able to browse our catalogue of children storybooks and use in-app-purchase to purchase each one.

What is the best way to achieve this, knowing that each individual storybook is already an app on its own?

Are there any ready-made bookshelf-type app template which we can use and customise to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bookshelf type app is probably best implemented as a collection view. I recommend using Apple's StoreKit to link to other apps. [StoreKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/)

Comment: StoreKit doesn't allow you to open other apps inside the first app. StoreKit provides in-app purchases features only.

Comment: You can't open an app inside of an other app but you can use custom URLSchemes to check if the app is already installed and bring them to it. If not installed they will have to use storekit to grab it

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to bundle several standalone apps into one app.  You have to get source code of each app and create a new app using them. However you can publish all your apps to appstore separately and make an 'app bundle' so users can download all your apps at once.